# Blender - photons "touching" faces

Tags: python, blender

Considering I have a mesh of a machine with both its external body and internal mechanism, I would like to develop a script in Blender that deletes all internal faces that are invisible from outside, as they represent industrial intellectual property.

I was thinking of illuminating the mesh with several lights. The script would then detect and select all faces that are being touched by any photon emitted by the lights.
Do you know if the Blender API has a function that tests if a face is being touched by photons?

Or... do you have another ideal to get the same result, it means deleting the internal faces?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/25jxst/easy_way_to_delete_internal_geometry/ or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18916/how-to-remove-interior-faces-while-keeping-exterior-faces-untouched ?